# Python server and java client not working properly

Tags: python, java, sockets, tcp

I want to make a socket between Java client

`
import java.util.*;

import java.net.*;

import java.io.*;

public class Main
{

public static void client()
{

```
    final int port = 2003;

    final String host = "localhost";

    try
    {

        Socket soc = new Socket(host, port);

        if(soc.isBound()){  
        System.out.println("socket binded");
```

}else   if(soc.isConnected()){

Scanner in = new Scanner(soc.getInputStream());

System.out.println("enter msg");

String x = in.nextLine();

PrintStream p = new PrintStream(soc.getOutputStream());

p.println("@client" + x);

} else if(soc.isClosed()){

System.out.println("Closed tunnel");

System.exit(0);

soc.close();

```
        }

    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {


    }

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    client();
}
```

}

`
Its having problem allowing me to use the scanner to send msg to Python server{I dunno how to make this}
PS : am new and dunno how to make this snippets formatted

Comment: "Its having problem" what problem exactly?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and format your code.

Comment: ```    import socket

port = 2003
host = 'localhost'
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
print '##binded'
s.listen(1)
print '##listening'
while 1:
  conn,addr = s.accept()
  msg = input(str('send msg'))
  conn.send(str(msg.encode()))
  data = conn.recv(1024)
  print '@client '+data.decode()

Comment: Sorry thats my server

Comment: I can't just use scanner and input() in both sides